# Using Python to fill dummy data into MySQL table

Tags: python, mysql

I'm messing around with the Sakila DB and I created a `director` table using the same schema as the `actor` table.

For those not familar, the `actor` table has 4 columns:

- actors_id
- first_name
- last_name
- last_update

The `director` table I created is similar in structure.

Now there is also a `film_actor` table, i think is used as a junction table since it has compound primary keys used to link the `actor` table to the `film` table.

Now I want to create a `director_film` table... you guessed it! To build a link with  films with its associated directors.

Problem is that there are 1000 films in Sakila. I want each director (I created 15) linked to each movie.

Is there a way to use Python to randomly assign a director to a film? This is on the localhost and I'm currently on the default 3306 port, using  root as user.

The primary keys for the `director` and `film` are auto-incremented starting at 1.

Comment: Why don't you do a loop generating 2 random numbers - the first one < 1000 and the second one < 15 - and then assign it?

Comment: You should be a little more specific about what you want: code to interact with the database? A SQL statement? Code to make this list of 1000 directorships? Some combination of the above?

Comment: Sorry about being unclear. Yes, code to interact with a database. I have  MySQL for Python module currently installed. If there is a way to do this just with SQL and skip Python altogether, I'm okay with that too.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that you have only one director per film, it would be prefered to add a field `director` to your `film` table.

Then you can run the following SQL query to set a random director (integer from 1 to 15) to each film:

```
UPDATE film SET director = FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *15 )
```

EDIT:

Copy the content of `film_actor` into `director_film`:

```
INSERT INTO director_film (SELECT * FROM film_actor )
```

Then generate a random director:

```
UPDATE director_film SET director = FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *15 )
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, it won't be a 1 to 1 relationship for each movie. For example I have both Wachowski brothers in my `director` table and they co-directed the Matrix series.